# Realm error: Invalid Value, expecting int and receiving: 0

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm with Swift for a query, but am receiving this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type int for property 'id' on object of type 'JournalEntryLine', but received: 0'

The JournalEntryLine class does have a property (Int) named `id`.

The code I'm using:

```
for item in idSet
    let idQuery = realm.objects(JournalEntryLine).filter("id = '\(item)' AND type = 'Debit'")
}
```

`idSet` is a set containing integers 0 and onward. I have confirmed that at least [0] is always in the set before running this query.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**-EDIT-**

- If you use: `id = 'YOUR_VAR_OR VALUE'` => means that id is a **String** (Ex: id ='4')
- But if you use: `id = YOUR_VAR_OR VALUE` => means that id is an **integer** (Ex: id = 4)

**NB:** So when your id is an integer don't use quotes ' '

---

Try this:

```
let idQuery = realm.objects(JournalEntryLine).filter("id = \(item) AND type = 'Debit'")
```

Transform **id = '\(item)'** to **id = \(item)** because id is an Integer, if you use quotes, il will consider id as a string.

Don't forget to **vote Up** if it helps you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Also it's helped to me:

```
let matchedMovieID = realm.objects(MovieID.self).filter("movieID == %@", idString).first
```

> Swift 4.2, XCode 10.0, Realm 3.14.1